# Set Content-type Apache NiFi dynamically

Tags: apache-nifi

I'am using Apache NiFi for a small webservice that should be able to serve static files(HTML, JavaScript, PNG, SVG, CSS). I have encountered an issue since NiFi not seems to set the Content-Type in the response header.

How can I configure the HandleHttpResponse-module to set the Content-Type header properly based on the requested filetype?

One way to do it is to use nested ifElse-statements in Expression Language but I don't think that would be best practice?

What I'am trying to achieve is that it should set Content-Type to `image/svg+xml` if the requested file is an SVG file, `text/css` if the requested file is an CSS-file etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide in a few lines your setup to serve this static site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [LookupAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupAttribute/) processor

put into SimpleKeyValueLookupService the map of file extension and Content-Type

```
svg = image/svg+xml
css = text/css
...
```

configure LookupAttribute to use SimpleKeyValueLookupService and set the dynamic property:

```groovy
mime.type = ${filename:replaceAll('.*\\.([^\\.]+)$','$1')}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the trick! Since I don't have a filename property i had to use: 

`mime.type = ${http.request.uri:contains('.'):ifElse(${http.request.uri:substringAfterLast('.')}, 'html')}`